# no bootable device, secure boot, UEFI after Ubuntu installation - Acer

Tags: boot, uefi, bios, acer, secure-boot

I own an [Acer Aspire 5720.](https://www.acer.com/ac/it/IT/content/support-product/548?b=1)

The laptop had an old version of Ubuntu. Due to networking issues, I had to restore the PC and install the newest version, 21.10.

I don't have CDs/DVDs burners on my PCs, so I burned the .iso in a USB drive, FAT32.
I proceeded with the installation of the OS on the laptop through the USB and everything worked as intended. In fact, I could try out the OS on the USB while installing it.

By starting the OS immediately after the installation, the screen stopped with the following message: **"no bootable device"** and **"grub_efi_secure_boot not found"** on GRUB. By using the BIOS, I made sure that the boot priorities were right. But it doesn't seem to be the actual problem.

According to some resources, it seems to be a matter of compatibility with new functionality from the newest OSs called *Secure Boot.* You need to set up appropriately the Secure Boot on UEFI and select the .iso Ubuntu file in your USB drive as trusted. However, the BIOS in my PC does **not** offer any options about Secure Boot, probably because both PC and BIOS are outdated. Meaning [I can't approach tutorials that seem to work only for PCs with Secure Boot, like this one.](https://youtu.be/AF1wSPFAq_A?t=101)

### Considering what I said above, these are my questions (mainly one):

- Is it possible to install the latest Ubuntu on my old PC which does not support Secure Boot and UEFI with the current USB drive?
- Is there a way to activate Secure Boot and UEFI options in another way?
- If the issue comes from the USB drive, is burning the OS on liveDVD/CD a possible fix?

Thank you for your reading! Keep in mind that most of the things I said come from what I found elsewhere. I'm not as cultured as it seems from the question.

Comment: (1) Yes, Ubuntu doesn't require secure boot. I suggest writing the ISO with balenaEtcher, and it should work fine with a flash drive instead of a CD. Most people use flash drives. I don't know if Ubuntu requires UEFI, though (2) You don't need secure boot. I use Ubuntu with UEFI, but without secure boot and it works fine (3) Most people use a flash drive. A USB stick should work fine

Comment: I've been able to use & install all currently supported releases on devices as old as from 2005 (older *i386* boxes to until 19.04 when 32-bit was finally dropped). uEFI/Secure boot isn't required.  How you write the ISO to thumb-drive can impact install; and I'd recommend QA-tested methods https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview

Comment: If you don't use the approved methods of writing an ISO to thumb-drive, ensure the software to write the ISO works for the release of Ubuntu you're using (ie. was your software capable of burning a 21.10 ISO image? or only older releases?).  The way ISOs boot can alter for each release as Ubuntu works to ensure all architectures/platforms boot the same, which can mean slight variations in ISOs meaning older software may not work correctly. 3rd party software is fine (eg. I use `mkusb`) but you must ensure it's suitable for the release (ie. fully updated to work for all releases).

Comment: What model Acer? Many systems have "Windows" or  "Other" as a setting. That really is UEFI Secure boot. My older system said use "Other" with Windows 7 as it did not support UEFI Secure Boot. You still can use UEFI booting. Some newer Acer require a control S to get additional settings in UEFI. And some Acer require UEFI Secure boot on & user password (never lose that or reset to blank) to have the added settings. Often easier to then have Secure Boot off, but Ubuntu will work with UEFI Secure Boot on. You may thne also need to specifically allow USB boot as that may not be considered secure.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have booted from the hard drive you were prompted to download Linux. Now you must go to you bios and change your boot setting to you drive that contains Linux. This is a very easy fix so I’m sure it will work. Please contact me if it does not work.